# Editing more than one field in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, submit

Currently, editing profile works for me. However, my problem is, only one element is successfully edited. I can echo previously saved data, and I can even type and edit each of the textboxes. Problem is, only the revision made on "profile" field is properly reflected. All the other fields remain the same.

here's what I have so far:
in controller page:

```
public function edit_profile() 
{
    //loads client profile and allows editing to be done
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $id = $this->auth_model->get_user_id();

    $data['client'] = $this->auth_model->get_client($id);
    $this->load->view('client/edit_profile', $data);
}
public function edit_profile_submit() 
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('auth_model');
    //$this->auth_model->edit_client_profile($this->auth_model->get_user_id(), $_POST['tagline']);      
    $this->auth_model->edit_client_profile($this->auth_model->get_user_id(), $_POST['profile']);
    //$this->auth_model->edit_client_profile($this->auth_model->get_user_id(), $_POST['billing_mode']); 
    redirect('client/view_profile?message=Profile updated.');

}
```

in model page:

```
public function edit_client_profile($id, $profile) 
{
    // allows client to edit his or her profile
    $data = array(
        //'tagline' => $tagline,
        'profile' => $profile
        //'billing_mode' => $billing_mode
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('client', $data);
}
```

I tried editing my controller and model page only to get errors so I commented the added lines for now instead. 
I am looking forward to any possible help.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't call edit_client_profile three separate times.  Create an array in your controller containing key values 'tagline', 'profile', and 'billing_mode'.  Then send all of that data to your edit_client_profile function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably because you have two undefined variables in your $data array each time you call the model.  Instead of creating the array in your model, create it in your controller:

```
$data = array(
     'tagline' => $_POST['tagline'],
     'profile' => $_POST['profile'],
     'billing_mode' => $_POST['billing_mode']
);
```

Then call the model

```
$this->auth_model->edit_client_profile($this->auth_model->get_user_id(), $data);
```

Remove the array creation from your model, change the second parameter being passed to `$data`:

```
public function edit_client_profile($id, $data) 
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('client', $data);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! I got it! It's working now! Thanks a lot! The only problem though is that billing mode (which is supposed to be chosen from a dropdown) does not reflect anything now.. I'll appreciate if you can also help me with that.. But I will also try my luck. Thanks again. Have a great day! ;)

Comment: Best bet is probably to review the codeigniter docs on dropdown http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html.  Glad it helped...please accept the answer if the issue is resolved

Comment: It sure did. Thanks again for your help! Have a nice day, Daniel!:)

Comment: Daniel, my dropdown function works well now. thanks for your help! ;)